# Wordpress paginate_links function give wrong url

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i want to setup my pagination in wordpress. This is my function call. The problem is, the function returned the urls to this `/taxonomy/term/paged/2`. But i want it to `/taxonomy/term/?page=2`. What is wrong?

```php
$pages = paginate_links( array_merge( [
            'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
            'format'       => '?page=%#%',
            'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
            'total'        => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
            'type'         => 'array',
            'show_all'     => false,
            'end_size'     => 3,
            'mid_size'     => 1,
            'prev_next'    => true,
            'prev_text'    => __( '« Prev' ),
            'next_text'    => __( 'Next »' ),
            'add_args'     => $add_args,
            'add_fragment' => ''
        ], $params )
```

Comment: I don’t have the ability to write any code for this at the moment, but I did this recently and I’m almost positive it was related to the `get_pagenum_link( 999999999 )` call you have. It is _that_ parameter that needs to be in the correct format, and `get_pagenum_link` is going to give you the system format, so try changing that to your expected pattern, with `?paged=999999999` in it